# bash syntax error "exec 11<<&-"

Tags: bash

Hi I have a bash scripts that's throwing an error:

scriptx.sh: line 276: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

The error is on last line of this snippet:

```
find * -type f > $loopfile
exec 11<$loopfile
while read file; do
  # Here some process....
  :
done
exec 11<<&-
```

What is the purpose of:

```
exec 11<$loopfile
exec 11<<&-
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two sections from the bash man page are relevant here.

> Redirecting Input
>
> Redirection of input causes the file whose name results from the expansion
>   of word to be opened for reading on  file  descriptor  n,  or  the
>   standard input (file descriptor 0) if n is not specified.
>
> ```
>    The general format for redirecting input is:
>
>           [n]<word
> ```

and

> Duplicating File Descriptors
>
> The redirection operator
>
> ```
>    [n]<&word
> ```
>
> is used to duplicate input file descriptors.  If word expands to one or
>   more digits, the file descriptor denoted by n is made to be a  copy  of
>   that  file  descriptor.   If  the  digits in word do not specify a file
>   descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs.  If word  evaluates
>   to  -,  file  descriptor n is closed.  If n is not specified, the
>   standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.

So the first line `exec 11<$loopfile` opens up file descriptor 11 to be opened for reading input and the input is set to come from `$loopfile`.

The second line `exec 11<<&-` then closes the (opened by the first line) descriptor 11... or rather it would were it not for the syntax error that chepner notes that I glossed over in my initial reading. The correct line should be `exec 11<&-` to close the fd.

To answer the follow-up question asked within the OP's self-answer unless this script uses fd 11 in that loop somewhere these lines seem to have no purpose. I would have normally assumed that this would be being done for use by `read` in that loop but that would require `-u 11` (and could as easily be done with `while read file; do ... done <$loopfile`).

Comment: That should probably be `exec 11<&-` to close descriptor 11; two `<<` would be a syntax error.

Comment: @chepner Good point. I had missed the error question in the OP and focused on the "what is this question". I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because to close a file descriptor it requires only one redirection operator `11<&-` and the script had two: `11<<&-`

A code sample on how to use it:

```
exec 11<$loopfile  # File descriptor 11 is made copy of $loopfile
while read -u 11 file; do
   : # process
done
exec 11<&-          # File descriptor 11 is closed.
```

What is the advantage of duplicating the file descriptor?